# Response error after uploading file with fetch request in react-native

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, form-data

I want to upload file(image, textfile, pdf etc) with FormData() and fetch request. Progress event working fine after completed progress event it gives **{"response":{"code":400,"api_status":0,"message":"Error while reading image."}}** .
How I can resolve this issue here is my code.

```
let uploadUrl = 'http://myurl.com:8080/api/v1/upload';
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('name', 'testName');
    data.append('photo', {
        uri: 'content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image-234.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'testPhotoName'
    });
    futch(uploadUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        body: data
    }, (progressEvent) => {
        const progress = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total;
        console.log(progress);
    }).then((res) => console.log(res), (err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Hope you have written "fetch", instead of futch. Also, did you checked for the data before making the API call ? Is it and object or string ?

Comment: I also have futch function like this one https://github.com/g6ling/React-Native-Tips/tree/master/How_to_upload_photo%2Cfile_in%20react-native